# SqlClientPermission failure in assembly loaded via reflection

Tags: asp.net, reflection, sqlclient

I am having a really tough time with a problem.  I have a web application that I have just modified that allows customers to supply custom assemblies that they can use to hook into an entity save pipeline.  These custom assemblies are loaded via reflection when an entity is persisted to the database.  They refer to a common DAL assembly that handles all of the data access.

I have a test server (Win2k3) where this system works flawlessly.  Now that I've pushed it out to my production server cluster (one Win2k3 and one Win2k8), my custom assembly bombs the first time it calls a DAL method that accesses the database (SQL2005).  The log information that I gather indicates that there is a failure in getting a SqlClientPermission.  Contrary to best practices, I have my web app running in Full Trust.  My custom assembly is strong named.

Are there any suggestions to where I can look for differences between my test server config and my production server configs?  If this is not the proper forum, which one is?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet that performs the data access as well as the specific error message it is returning?

Comment: they were too long, so I put them in as new "answers"

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue without the reflection. I was moving a compiled project from my Win 2k3 machine to Win 2k8. 
- In IIS go under the bin folder where you dll's are to and right click. 
- Go to "Edit Permissions...". 
- At the very bottom of the "General" tab there may be a button saying UnBlock.

Win 2k8 doesn't seem to like the dll's copied from another environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more info than I can put in a comment...

It would appear now that this is a Win2k8 vs Win2k3 issue since I no longer get any exceptions in the logs from the Win2k3 server in our cluster.

Basically, what happens is that our entity save pipeline checks to see if the entity type being saved implements a certain interface.  If so, then the application goes out to the database to retrieve the assembly and class name of the class that implements the customer-specific pre- and post- save functionality.  Those assemblies are under the "App_Data" folder in an folder called "Assemblies\".  The application then loads the assembly; uses reflection to instantiate the proper class from that assembly as an interface, then calls the pre and post save methods on that interface to perform the customer specific actions for that particular entity type.  In our case, this custom action performs some database operations using our DAL (which uses LLBLGen, FWIW) entity classes.

My initial issue was that I was getting a SecurityException about not allowing partially trusted callers, so I decorated the assemblies that are used with the "AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers" attribute.

In my extension assemby that gets loaded, I instantiate a SqlClientPermission and "Assert()" it, but I haven't anywhere actually granted that permission (except that my web app runs in FullTrust).

Thanks for whatever help you can offer...

-Matthew

Here is the .ToString() output of the exception that gets thrown:

```
Error performing post-save operation on entity 373c595e-843b-45a1-82d0-aa166daf75de of type SS2DAL.EntityClasses.SurveyResponseEntity: SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.ORMQueryExecutionException: An exception was caught during the execution of a retrieval query: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.. Check InnerException, QueryExecuted and Parameters of this exception to examine the cause of this exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.RetrievalQuery.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission
The first permission that failed was:
<IPermission
version="1"
AllowBlankPassword="False">
<add KeyRestrictions=""
KeyRestrictionBehavior="AllowOnly"/>
</IPermission>

The demand was for:
<IPermission
version="1"
AllowBlankPassword="False">
<add KeyRestrictions=""
KeyRestrictionBehavior="AllowOnly"/>
</IPermission>

The granted set of the failing assembly was:
<PermissionSet
version="1">
<IPermission
version="1"
Access="Open"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Allowed="ApplicationIsolationByUser"
UserQuota="512000"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Window="SafeTopLevelWindows"
Clipboard="OwnClipboard"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
PublicKeyBlob="0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B55C03865E07BCB230B04EF7D9ACF1E7BF41C618DB1327895C25328446039F51CF237A50989E542D3FA9BB5991D303388C5AAC7AE4E071CD7B42B96B16256FF905EC610107DB2A0872E971253919BA528187489FC89FD083118F562319BF3B66CB79035EC50D2291561D4F2B9733AD5E0ECD9BFF9B80B94C40F5888D4E1C5BDD"
Name="ProjectHelpers.Extensions"
AssemblyVersion="2.2009.208.1821"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Url="file://dc01.bizspeed.datacenter/websites/sitesupervisor files/prjh/ProjectHelpers.Extensions.dll"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Zone="Internet"/>
<IPermission
version="1"
Level="SafePrinting"/>
</PermissionSet>

The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
ProjectHelpers.Extensions, Version=2.2009.208.1821, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4405fd38c7d52787
The method that caused the failure was:
SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.EntityBase2 AfterSave(SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.EntityBase2, SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file://dc01.bizspeed.datacenter/websites/sitesupervisor files/prjh/ProjectHelpers.Extensions.dll
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.RetrievalQuery.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.ExecuteSingleRowRetrievalQuery(IRetrievalQuery queryToExecute, IEntityFields2 fieldsToFill, IFieldPersistenceInfo[] fieldsPersistenceInfo)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.FetchEntityUsingFilter(IEntityFields2 fieldsToFetch, IFieldPersistenceInfo[] persistenceInfos, IRelationPredicateBucket filter)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.FetchEntityUsingFilter(IEntity2 entityToFetch, IPrefetchPath2 prefetchPath, Context contextToUse, IRelationPredicateBucket filter, ExcludeIncludeFieldsList excludedIncludedFields)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.FetchEntity(IEntity2 entityToFetch, IPrefetchPath2 prefetchPath, Context contextToUse, ExcludeIncludeFieldsList excludedIncludedFields)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.FetchEntity(IEntity2 entityToFetch, IPrefetchPath2 prefetchPath)
   at ProjectHelpers.Extensions.SurveyResponseSaveHelper.AfterSave(EntityBase2 entity, DataAccessAdapterBase adapter)
   at SS2.RemoteObjects.DataPortal.EntitySaveWithoutRemoting(EntityBase2 entity, AuditSettings auditSettings, AuthTicket at)  [NDC:(null)]
```

Comment: Have you checked to see that the ASP.NET permissions were the same on the Win 2K8 and Win 2K3 servers, they could be running under different process identities and causing issues. Are both servers the same version of IIS?

Comment: both applications an app pool the identity of which is a domain user.  The Win2k3 server is IIS6 and the Win2k8 is IIS7.  (Can you upgrade IIS6 to IIS7 on Win2k3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method in the reflected object that bombs:

```
    public EntityBase2 AfterSave(EntityBase2 entity, DataAccessAdapterBase adapter)
    {
        SurveyResponseEntity response = entity as SurveyResponseEntity;

        if (response.IsComplete) // we only really want to do this if the survey has been completed.
        {
            SurveyEntity survey = new SurveyEntity(response.SurveyRefId);
            IPrefetchPath2 questionSetPath = new PrefetchPath2((int)SS2DAL.EntityType.SurveyEntity);
            IPredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression(QuestionSetFields.Current == 1);
            questionSetPath.Add(SurveyEntity.PrefetchPathQuestionSetCollection, 1, filter)
                .SubPath.Add(QuestionSetEntity.PrefetchPathQuestionPageCollection)
                    .SubPath.Add(QuestionPageEntity.PrefetchPathQuestionCollection);

            if (adapter.FetchEntity(survey, questionSetPath))
            {
                // we need to instantiate the survey template save handler from this survey response (if it exists)
                // then execute

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(survey.PostSaveAssemblyName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(survey.PostSaveClassName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string assemblyPath = (new FileService()).GetRootAssemblyURL();

                        Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, survey.PostSaveAssemblyName)));

                        if (asm != null)
                        {
                            Type t = asm.GetType(survey.PostSaveClassName);
                            ISurveyPostSaveHandler cls = (ISurveyPostSaveHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                            if (cls != null)
                            {
                                cls.AfterSave(response, survey, adapter);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // at some point, we need to add some logging here.
                        Logger.ErrorFormat("There was an error post-processing survey response {0} from survey {1}: {2}", response.SurveyResponseId, survey.Name, ex.ToString());
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.ErrorFormat("Could not post process response {0} because the parent survey could not be located", response.SurveyResponseId);
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Could not post process response {0} because the parent survey could not be located", response.SurveyResponseId));
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    #endregion
}
```